# How to find the lowest value out of a set of variables

Tags: c++

Essentially, I have a dice rolling program that rolls 4 dice, then gives you the output. I would like to add an additional function that finds the lowest value of these rolls, and adds the other three rolls together, outputting that result.

This is the current program

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <cstdlib>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
                int d61;
                srand(time(NULL));
                d61 = rand() % 6 + 1;

                Sleep(1000);

                int d62;
                srand(time(NULL));
                d62 = rand() % 6 + 1;

                Sleep(1000);

                int d63;
                srand(time(NULL));
                d63 = rand() % 6 + 1;

                Sleep(1000);

                int d64;
                srand(time(NULL));
                d64 = rand() % 6 + 1;
                cout << endl << "You rolled a " << d61 << ", " << d62 << ", " << d63 << ", and a " << d64 << "." << endl;
                //Find lowest number
                //Add other three numbers together, make that a variable called 'roll'
                //cout << "The highest 3 rolls added together are " << roll << "." << endl;
    }
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look at [`std::min()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min).  Or put the values in an array and use [`std::min_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element)

Comment: As a rule, you want to avoid using `srand`/`rand` in modern C++. If you insist on using them anyway, you at least want to only call `srand` once per program.

Comment: And each call to srand is **nonrandom** since you're using time as the seed, assuming sleep 1000 is fairly accurate, so you're not adding more randomness by calling srand multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just compare them all:

```
int dmin = d61;
if (d62 < dmin) dmin = d62;
if (d63 < dmin) dmin = d63;
if (d64 < dmin) dmin = d64;
cout << "The minimum is " << dmin << endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::min` can take an initializer list, so you can compare them all at once.

```
auto minimum = std::min({d61, d62, d63, d64});
```

and you can find the sum of the other three (that are not the minimum one) with a bit of math:

```
auto sum_of_three = d61 + d62 + d63 + d64 - minimum;
```